# Get response in a list. Change sql to Linq query to aggregate the data

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, linq

I am working on a project to get school grades for student for
each class

```
public class StudentResponse
{
    public string StudentName { get; set }
    public string StudentClass { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<StudentGradesTests> StudentGrades { get; set; }
}

public class StudentGradesTests
{
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfTestsforEachClass { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalMarks { get; set; }
}
```

Response required list of student responses:

```
{
"StudentName":"Mark",
"StudentClass":"5th"
"StudentGrades" :[ 
{"Subject": "Maths","NumberOfTestsforeachClass": "3","TotalMarks": "285"},
{"Subject": "English","NumberOfTestsforeachClass": "4","TotalMarks": "345"},
{"Subject": "Science","NumberOfTestsforeachClass": "3","TotalMarks": "255"},
]

"StudentName":"Adam",
"StudentClass":"6th"
"StudentGrades" :[ 
{"Subject": "Maths","NumberOfTestsforeachClass": "3","TotalMarks": "185"},
{"Subject": "English","NumberOfTestsforeachClass": "4","TotalMarks": "245"},
{"Subject": "Science","NumberOfTestsforeachClass": "3","TotalMarks": "256"},
]

}
```

Data in the database:

```
Students             Classes    

id | Name       id  | class | studentid 
1  | Mark       1   |  5th  |  1
2  | Adam       2   |  6th  |  2

SubjectDetails 

id  | class    | classId | studentid | Tests | Marks
1   | Science  |  1      |   1       |  1    |  80
2   | Science  |  1      |   1       |  1    |  90
3   | Science  |  1      |   1       |  1    |  85
4   | Science  |  1      |   2       |  1    |  100
5   | Science  |  1      |   2       |  1    |  76
```

I have a query that returns all this but I have hard time changing it to Linq

```
SELECT 
    st.id, st.Name, c.class, sd.subject,
    COUNT(sd.tests) AS NumberOfTestsforeachClass, 
    SUM(sd.Marks) AS TotalMarks
FROM
    Students st 
INNER JOIN
    Classes c ON st.id = c.studentid 
INNER JOIN
    SubjectDetails sd ON sd.classId = c.id AND sd.studentid = c.studentid
GROUP BY 
    st.id, st.Name, c.Class
```

Now I would like to change this SQL to Linq in the response like I mentioned above

```
var response = from st in students
           join c in classes on st.id equals c.studentid
           join sd in subjectDetails on sd.classId equals c.id && sd.studentid equals c.studentid
           group st.id,st.Name,c.Class into res
           select new StudentResponse
               {
                StudentName = res.key.Name,
                StudentClass = res.key.Class
                StudentGrades = // Not sure what do I need here. Need some help here to create a list of StudentGrades
                }
```

Need help get student grades test in response as Enumerable rather than having multiple student response for one student with same class

Comment: Can you perhaps show us the expected format of the output.

Comment: LINQ isn't SQL. It's the language used by ORMs like EF or NHibernate. If you create the appropriate relations you won't have to write JOINs yourself. You could use `from st in students from sd in st.Details group by new {st.Id, st.Name,sd.Class.Class} into g....`

Comment: @Rakesh Hi Rakesh, There is a response inside the question. Studentgrade tests should be a list of each student for each class. Let me know if you have any questions. We can chat about it